# Howto access Request.QueryString from anywhere?

Tags: c#

I've gotten an error with the Request.QueryString and I cant seem to find any solution..

```
 public static DataTable SelectFrom(string Table, string Felt, string query)
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + Felt + " = @parameter", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", Request.QueryString[query]);

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: use `catch (Exception ex)` and log/debug it, instead of the empty `catch`, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Request.QueryString[query] will work in a page not in a class. Use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", query);

Comment: I got the error: The name 'Request' does not exist in te current context.

Comment: SQL Injection is possible.

Comment: Accessing Request from someting like a DataAccessLayer is super wrong. Do that before you call SelectForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `QueryString` inside `static` method and there is no `Request object` inside this method so you need to use.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

in static method.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've got all the help I needed. HttpContext.Current. Was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your code is inside a separate class or an assembly (not inside a page class), If yes use

`httpcontext.current.request.QueryString`

Comment: "Seems your code is inside a class or an assembly" - where else such code can be?

Comment: Well, when your phrase it like this it looks strange, i meant not inside the page class directly

Answer (score 0):

Let us know the error that you got.

Always before using Request.QueryString you need to check it for null, like

```
if(Request.QueryString[query] != null && Request.QueryString[query].ToString() != string.empty)
```

Comment: Check whether your code is in page class or standalone class, because "Request" does not work in standalone class as it is the property of page class.